# Javascript/jQuery: Check if text is within viewport of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, overflow, viewport

I have text within an element whose font size is `font-size: 4vw`, this means that if the text is too long, only the beginning of the text will remain within the viewport.

eg: |Example Long Text| becomes |Example Lon|. I'm looking to write a script such that rather than do that, it will become |Example L..| to indicate that there is more content. However, I don't know how to check if the text has left the viewport.

Any ideas?

Comment: Compute the height of the text container, compare it to the height of the window. If it's too large, shrink the text and repeat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use JS to solve this - it can be done with pure CSS using the `text-overflow` property.  This saves you from having to work out some of the complexities of coding this yourself.

Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/37x7jyze/